# How to solve the error for PHP file including (in PHP) (2 files on 2 web servers)?

Tags: php, apache, webserver

What is the main problem for PHP file including (in PHP) (2 files on 2 web servers)?

---

1. I have 2 web servers:

a. The first web server: http:// web1.com/, it includes a PHP file: main_core.php (is placed at http:// web1.com/main_core.php).
In this PHP file (main_core.php), I have created an PHP function (is an OBJECT function, is not a CLASS function): main_function.

b. The second web server: http:// web2.com/, it includes a PHP file: user_interface.php (is placed at http:// web2.com/user_interface.php).
In this PHP file (user_interface.php), I have included (main_core.php) on the first server (http:// web1.com/), by file include syntax: include 'http:// web1.com/main_core.php';
and I have called main_function (a function in http:// web1.com/main_core.php).

I haved contacted with web server provider, and I have turned on allow_url_fopen, allow_url_include (both 2 web servers) and restarted it 3 times. But, I always get this warning (in http:// web2.com/user_interface.php) when I run it.

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function **main_function()** in **http:// web2.com/user_interface.php** on line **32**.

---

2. My web server supports Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5 + PEAR (and others).
3. If I set main_core.php and user_interface.php in one (1) server (for proving that both 2 my PHP files are OK!). Change include syntax (in user_interface.php) into: include 'main_core.php'; , it works perfectly and I have no error when I run user_interface.php.

---

What is the main problem of this error? How to solve it?

P/S: Do not suggest using API or setting 2 files in one (1) web server.

---

Thank you very much !

Comment: do you understand the difference between http and ftp ?? you cant add a php file of one server into another and thats meaningfull

Comment: Yea that won't work.  When you request the PHP file from the other server via http it will have been executed, not raw PHP as you're expecting.  If you really wanted to do something like this and were not worried about security you would have to save the PHP as plain text like a `.txt` file then `eval()` it on the other end.